# jQuery promises twice in ExecuteQueryAsync

Tags: promise, jquery-deferred

I am trying to get terms from a managed metadata service using JavaScript, Some of the terms has sub terms so I need to use nested deferred (jquery promises). following is my code.

```
$.when(GetTerms()).done(function (topMenu) {
     myDoElement.html(topMenu);
});
function GetTerms(){
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   var arr1 = [];
   //some variables and code here
   clientCtx.load(terms);
   clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
      var termsEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
      while (termsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
         // here adds som html using arr1.push("");
         var currentTerm = termsEnumerator.get_current();
         $.when(GetSubTerms(currentTerm)).done(function (childItemsHtml) {
             //adding sub terms
              arr1.push(childItemsHtml);
         });             
       }
       //push closing html elements into arr1
       dfd.resolve(arr1.join(''));
   }),
   Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
     dfd.reject(args.get_message());
   }));
   return dfd.promise();
 }

 function GetSubTerms(parent) {
     var dfdChild = $.Deferred();
     var arr2 = [];
     var childs = parent.get_terms();
     clientCtx.load(childs);
     clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
         //adding som html to arr1 using push
         var childsEnumerator = childs.getEnumerator();
         while (childsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
             var childTerm = childsEnumerator.get_current();
             //pushing elements into arr2
         }
         //pushing closing html elements into arr2
         dfdChild.resolve(arr1.join(''));
     }),
     Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
         dfdChild.reject(args.get_message());
      }));
     return dfdChild.promise();
 }
```

If I don't use GetSubTerms it works good for top terms (parents) it returns all parents, but the problem is when I use GetSubTerms it returns only first parent.

Comment: What does `Function.createDelegate` do?

Comment: [Shereen Qumsieh](http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2013/10/31/using-jquery-promises-deferreds-with-sharepoint-2013-jsom/ "Shereen Qumsieh") explains Function.createDelegate: "Notice on line 15 we create a simple object containing our Deferred and our SP.List object. We pass that into our Function.createDelegate calls in order to invoke the callbacks in a way that sets their context (this) to that object! This is the way to pass parameters into callbacks using executeQueryAsync."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> while (termsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
>    // here adds som html using arr1.push("");
>    var currentTerm = termsEnumerator.get_current();
>    $.when(GetSubTerms(currentTerm)).done(function (childItemsHtml) {
>      //adding sub terms
>      arr1.push(childItemsHtml);
>    });             
> }
> //push closing html elements into arr1
> dfd.resolve(arr1.join(''))
> ```

That does not work. `GetSubTerms` is still asynchronous, so `arr1` will not contain the `childItemsHtml`s *when* the `dfd.resolve()` is called. You will need to wait for the promises to finish before calling that! Do something like this:

```
function GetTerms(){
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  // some variables and code here
  clientCtx.load(terms);
  clientCtx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    dfd.resolve(terms.getEnumerator());
  }),
  Function.createDelegate(this, function (sender, args) {
    dfd.reject(args.get_message());
  }));

  return dfd.then(function(termsEnumerator) {
    var promises = [];
    while (termsEnumerator.moveNext()) {
      // here adds som html using promises.push($.when(""));
      var currentTerm = termsEnumerator.get_current();
      promises.push( GetSubTerms(currentTerm) );
    }
    //push closing html element promise into promises
    return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
       var arr1 = $.map(arguments, function(args){return args[0];});
       //adding sub terms
       return arr1.join('');
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, do you mean that I need to change GetTerms method (like your code) and I don't need to change my GetSubTerms method?

Comment: I changed my GetTerms method as you wrote (didn't change GetSubTerms), When It comes back to line return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function(arr1) { return arr1.join('');}. it seems that arr1 is html dom not an array and it contains only first sub term not all of them.

Comment: Yes, `GetSubTerms` does work correctly, doensn't it? No , `arr1` should contain the results of each of the `promises` - but you're right I forgot something.